# ARMv7A instruction

Tags: arm, instruction-set

I have a question about the following ARMv7A instruction: ldrh r0, [ r1 ], r2. Considering the entire fetch-decode-execute cycle, how many bytes does the ISA suggest are transferred between the micro-processor and memory?

Is it 6 because first it loads half a word (2 bytes) from memory, then it writes a 4-byte word to a register?

Comment: Registers are inside the processor, not in memory at all.  2 bytes of data are loaded (assuming no cache), but you aren't counting instruction-fetch.  In ARM mode at least (maybe also Thumb), that's a 4-byte instruction.

Comment: loads are the width of the bus generally and then the processor extracts the bytes it was interested in.  read a byte from 0x1001 and it is going to read 32, 64 or 128 bits from 0x1000 as there is no byte/lane mask on a read.

Comment: the isa is not in control of the bus between processor and  memory.  arm has variations on amba/axi/ahb which you can easily get the documentation for.

Comment: and that is just the arm bus between the core and the chip which is not an arm thing, and the chip has its own caches, controllers etc, which are also not driven by the isa, they are the choice of the designers of the chip and off chip interfaces.

Comment: if the transaction is unaligned it can turn into two bus cycles each taking the bus width (again no byte masks on a load).

Comment: So is it 6 bytes transferred after all?

Comment: Also I assume by memory the question means the memory unit in the processor, not the main memory, which is why it specifies micro-processor ?

Comment: you have not provided enough information to determine that.  the isa does not dictate, the implemetation combined with address does.  it definitely will not be 6 bytes.

Comment: armv7a is not a processor it is the architecture specification.  I assume you have an AXI bus on your core?  And what size is that bus?   Are you aligned or unaligned?  And what address overall (lower handful of bits), etc...

Comment: so the term memory implies here system memory or at least something on the other end of the processor bus (chip vendor not arm). and asking what is between the processor and memory implies that transfer which was already answered above.   If you want to also talk about the register file (which is an sram most likely, but depends on the implementation, which you would need access to, and might not be allowed to even tell us you have access to according to the nda).   Then that is definitely not 2 bytes wide, it would be 32 or 32 plus parity or 32 plus ecc being 32 bit registers.

Comment: If not a register file then it is just a register, 32 bits, as part of the logic.  If this is some homework assignment, then just put whatever answer the professor wants, right or wrong, and learn the truth later.

Comment: It is zero, if the value is L1/L2 cache. It is complex as it may fetch a cache line. So even though it is requesting only two bytes, it may actually read and entire cache line from memory. It absolutely never read/writes register to/from memory as others have already noted.  So the answer is zero or 32bytes (cache line size).